# Is there official name of sub-subdomain (i.e. "test2" of FQDN "test2.test1.example.com")

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, subdomain

Is there an official name for a sub-subdomain: i.e. `test2` of FQDN `test2.test1.example.com`; if not, is this expression commonly used?

Also, what if there is more granular FQDN such as `test3.test2.test1.example.com`? So, `test3` should be like sub-sub-subdomain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not special word for that. DNS system works as distributed system where there is trusted **root** (.) where is information about **Top Level Domains** (e.g. com, org, eu, gov,...). To keep the trust and prevent Man-in-the-middle attack there is available *DNSSEC* extension to proof the validity of the answer in case it is applied (it is per domain setting).

Next to it you can find terminology related to how "deep" in the tree is the domain located so **2nd level domain** (e.g. google.com, serverfault.com,...), **3rd level domain** (e.g. www.google.com, reed.co.uk, ...).

In case you really need some specific name I would think about combination so 2nd level subdomain for example.com - but I have never see or hear this kind of wording in DNS system...

Comment: Thank you Kamil, understand that!

Answer (score 1):

RFC 8499 is the standard for DNS terminology:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8499

It has this:

> Subdomain:  "A domain is a subdomain of another domain if it is
> contained within that domain.  This relationship can be tested by
> seeing if the subdomain's name ends with the containing domain's
> name."  (Quoted from [RFC1034], Section 3.1) For example, in the
> host name "nnn.mmm.example.com", both "mmm.example.com" and
> "nnn.mmm.example.com" are subdomains of "example.com".  Note that
> the comparisons here are done on whole labels; that is,
> "ooo.example.com" is not a subdomain of "oo.example.com".

As you can see "subdomain" covers any kind of level "below" the domain.
`nnn.mmm.example.com` is a subdomain of both `com`, `example.com`, and `mmm.example.com` depending on how you want to view it.

Comment: Thank you Patrick, really appreciate your detailed comment.  I will check the RFC by myself too.